# After migration to Angular 15, ng build gives an error " '4th-party-module' module has no exports" in third party library

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm tagging it as Angular related problem because I suspect it's connected with Angular's build toolset.

I have a strange error when building my application after migrating it to Angular 15. This application depends on `ngx-markdown` and `ngx-markdown` depends on `marked`. Errors are inside `ngx-markdown`. Here they are:

```bash
./node_modules/ngx-markdown/fesm2020/ngx-markdown.mjs:8:0-52 - Error: export 'Renderer' (reexported as 'MarkedRenderer') was not found in 'marked' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/ngx-markdown/fesm2020/ngx-markdown.mjs:127:31-39 - Error: export 'Renderer' (imported as 'Renderer') was not found in 'marked' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/ngx-markdown/fesm2020/ngx-markdown.mjs:141:20-28 - Error: export 'Renderer' (imported as 'Renderer') was not found in 'marked' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/ngx-markdown/fesm2020/ngx-markdown.mjs:236:72-80 - Error: export 'Renderer' (imported as 'Renderer') was not found in 'marked' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/ngx-markdown/fesm2020/ngx-markdown.mjs:331:20-38 - Error: export 'marked' (imported as 'marked') was not found in 'marked' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/ngx-markdown/fesm2020/ngx-markdown.mjs:331:62-74 - Error: export 'marked' (imported as 'marked') was not found in 'marked' (module has no exports)
```

The above line numbers are not corresponding to any imports. Errors seem to be not matching the given file. Most of those lines are even not that long as column numbers indicate. What could this mean?

`ngx-markdown`, `marked` and `@types/marked` are installed in proper versions:

```
├── @types/marked@4.0.8
└─┬ ngx-markdown@15.1.2
  ├── @types/marked@4.0.8 deduped
  └── marked@4.3.0
```

There is an issue on *ngx-markdown*'s github page describing similar problem (https://github.com/jfcere/ngx-markdown/issues/375) but provided solutions seem to be random and not working for me. I've tried many proposed solutions (starting from fresh clone, cleaning all possible caches, mixing versions a little bit) and nothing helps. I've checked configuration 10 times and everything seems to be right. I've inspected the contents of directories with those three modules inside `node_modules` and all seems to be OK, `marked` properly defines exports. It's a big app with many dependencies and after migration only this one problem is left and it can be reproduced on other machines.

Any idea how to troubleshoot deeper this problem, or what other solution could I try?

Comment: Guessing you have, but have you tried the ol' remove node_modules, package-lock.json, and reinstalling dependencies? `rm -rf node_modules` `rm package-lock.json` ?  Second thing is to check the dependency tree: `npm ls`, make sure you have no conflicts or multiples of the same package. Those are the only two things I can think of that I didn't see on your question or the github issue.